# Why does Visual Studio only sometimes ask me if I want to rename code elements when I rename their associated files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, rename

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 ver 15.5.0 Preview 2.0, but I've seen this in other versions.  When I rename a code file in the solution explorer, *sometimes* it asks me if I want to rename the associated code element as well:

[image]

Other times it does not.  Under what circumstances does it *not* do that so I can try to avoid them?

**EDIT:**

I found one easy way to repro my undesired behavior.  Create a project.  Create two folders in the project.  Create a class file in one folder.  Drag the class file into the second folder.  Rename the class file; note you are NOT prompted.

Comment: I believe it only does that with a single class/interface in a single namespace.  If there are other "root" objects in the file like an enum or another class, it won't do it, presumably because it doesn't want to assume which one corresponds to the file name.

Comment: I rarely have multiple root objects in a single file.  This behavior happens regardless.

Comment: Another condition is that the file name and the root object must match exactly in order to get the prompt.

Comment: I don't know what the rules are for determining whether it should ask it, but one that I have observed: if the type that would be renamed is generic, it won't ask. So, e.g., if you rename `Foo.cs` to `Bar.cs` and the class in `Foo.cs` is `class Foo<T> { }`, it won't ask but if it is just `class Foo { }` it usually will. I would guess that it's because the type name, as the compiler thinks of it, includes the generic parameters and therefore doesn't match exactly. However, as I said, this is just an observation--I don't know the complete set of rules.

Comment: Okay see edit.  I discovered one way this happens.

Comment: That seems to be also a problem with the name not matching exactly. If you drag it from folder `F1` to folder `F2` but the type is still in the namespace `F1` then the types don't match exactly and it won't ask. If you drag the file between folders as you said and then change the namespace to what is expected from files added to the new folder name before trying to rename the file, it asks whether to rename the element as you want.

Comment: Ahh yes, you're right about that @kanders84152

Comment: If this *really* matters then you could simply [discover it in the code](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/master/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Managed.VS/VSResources.Designer.cs#L462).

Comment: @HansPassant That's fine assuming I don't make mistakes.  The dialog is a handy reminder.